# LDAP and Custom AuthenticationStateProvider integration in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Trying to find a way to get authentication done through ldap and a custom authentication state provider. Services that have been added:

```
 services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider,Login_Logic>();
```

Also these configure settings in startup.cs:

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

My logic for the ldap and authstateprovider - pretty lost on integrating these two with each other

```
 public class Login_Logic:AuthenticationStateProvider
{

    
    public UserData user { get; set; } 
    public string loginattempt { get; set; }
    
    public bool userisauthenticated { get; set; }

    SearchResult result { get; set; }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
  {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name)
    }, "Fake authentication type");
    }

    private async Task dothething()
    {

       
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry();
        entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myldap");
        entry.Username = user.UserName;
        entry.Password = user.Password;


        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + user.UserName + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("phone");
        if (user.UserName != null && user.Password != null)
        {
            try
            {
                result = search.FindOne();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    loginattempt = "Success";
                    userisauthenticated = true;

                }

            }
            catch
            {
                loginattempt = "Wrong username or password";
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Make `dothething` return SearchResult and call it inside `GetAuthenticationStateAsync`.